# Using Javascript to move elements positioned using CSS Top Bottom Left Right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container that does not have any set dimensions. I want the size of the container to be driven by it's contents. Like so:

```
    #containerTL{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: default;    
    }

    #content{
    position:relative;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
    cursor: default;    
    }

    <div id="containerTL"><div id="content"></div></div>
```

I also want to move the position of the container and have it's contents come along for the ride. Setting the position by modifying the containers style.top & style.left is easy, the problem I have is that the elements may be positioned using "bottom" or "right". Without set dimensions, the container grows, rather than move when I set the top and left properties.

I think I understand the problem. Lets say the style specifies a bottom and left position, and I update the top and left properties using javascript, the top and left properties get set, but the style specifies a bottom property.

I suppose I could always set the bottom and right properties to "auto" once I update top and left... but what if I wanted to be able to send each element back to it's original position, generically, without writing a special case for each element.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVXFT/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
this.style.right = '';
this.style.left = '';
this.style.top = '';
this.style.bottom = '';
```

and it will unset anything you set via `.style` and revert back to what you defined in the stylesheet.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVXFT/2/) for an example.  Clicking once moves it, clicking again should move it back to the original position.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V8vu6/)

You need the following code for the other two sides

```
this.style.bottom = "auto";
this.style.right = "auto";
```